# TileOverlay not rendering tiles in Google Maps Android app

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an Android application that loads tiles from a URL. Following a code sample from Google, I have the following function:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mapView = googleMap;
    mapView.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    LatLng baseLocation = new LatLng(37.745446, -122.459264);
    mapView.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(baseLocation).title("Marker"));
    mapView.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(baseLocation));
    mapView.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(5));

    TileProvider tileProvider = new UrlTileProvider(256, 256) {
        @Override
        public synchronized URL getTileUrl(int x, int y, int z) {
            String formattedUrl = String.format(Locale.US, TILE_SERVER_URL, x, y, z);
            URL url = null;

            try {
                url = new URL(formattedUrl);
                Log.d("TILE_URL", url.toString());
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                throw new AssertionError(ex);
            }
            return url;
        }
    };

    tiles = mapView.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().zIndex(0.0f).tileProvider(tileProvider).visible(true));
}
```

This has already been implemented in our iOS version and works as expected. Furthermore, I have verified that the URLs returned to the console in this function definitely result in a tile image being returned.

I'm primarily an iOS person and need some insight here. No tiles show up on the map. I've played around with zIndex of the tile overlay with no effect.

Can anyone offer some advice here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you followed Google's [TileOverlayDemoActivity example](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/java/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/TileOverlayDemoActivity.java): if this is the case, you have to update the URL format protocol from **http** to **https**, as follows:

```
private static final String MOON_MAP_URL_FORMAT =
        "https://mw1.google.com/mw-planetary/lunar/lunarmaps_v1/clem_bw/%d/%d/%d.jpg";
```

It took me ages to figure it out, I hope this helps.